# SwiftUI layout inside VStack using ViewModifiers

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui, vstack

I have a simple view with two texts. Its `body` is like this:

```swift
VStack {
    Text("One")
    Text("Two")
    Text("Three")
}
```

this produces a view like:

[image: Existing layout]

But what I would like is, using only modifiers to the `Text` views (i.e. no `HStack` with `Spacer`s), achieve a layout like:

[image: Desired layout]

Is this currently possible? I was hoping making the `Text`s full width somehow and then just using the text alignment would work but haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... as there are no any additional conditions or restrictions, with just added two lines of code

Demo in Preview (blue border is just a selection in code)

[image: demo]

```
    VStack {
        Text("One")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        Text("Two")
        Text("Three")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Can you foresee any downsides of using this? i.e. is it "weird" using a frame's alignment for text alignment?

Comment: @KerrM, no, actually it is aligned not text (ie, string) but entire view inside provided frame. So if you inter very very long text it fill and wrap in a usual way. Moreover as there is no hardcode change orientation or layout will be handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this could be possible. You could define a modifier like:

```
extension View {
    func horizontalAlignment(_ alignment: HorizontalAlignment) -> some View {
        Group {
            if alignment == .leading {
                HStack {
                    self
                    Spacer()
                }
            } else if alignment == .trailing {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    self
                }
            } else {
                self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
VStack {
    Text("One")
        .horizontalAlignment(.leading)
    Text("Two")
        .horizontalAlignment(.center)
    Text("Three")
        .horizontalAlignment(.trailing)
}
```

Of course, multiple approaches are possible.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to just set the frame:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("One")
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       alignment: .leading)
            Text("Two")
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
            Text("Three")
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       alignment: .trailing)

        }
    }
}
```